# If Statement to execute part of code if is ID JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I try to make some changes in Javascript code. I am new at this point, at the start of learning Javascript.
My problem is:
I have for example this structure

```
<div id="top-offer">
<div class="image-container">
Javascript Code generates a slider with 3 Visibile images
</div>
</div>
<div id="supper-offer">
<div class="image-container">
Javascript Code generates a slider with 3 Visibile images
</div>
</div>
```

I need some how to change this code for Id=supper-offer to show only 2 images instead of 3 (slidesToShow: 3)

```
$('.evo-slider:not(.slick-initialized)').slick({
    //dots: true,
    arrows: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 480, // xs
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 768, // sm
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 992, // md
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

How to make IF statement that will execute this code with "slidesToShow: 2" for div with ID=supper-offer some thing like

```
    if id=supper-offer  {
    slidesToShow: 2
}
    else{
    slidesToShow: 3
    }
```

Comment: You can't put statements in the middle of an expression like an object literal.  You should use the `?:` conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the ternary operator:

```
slidesToShow: (id === supper-offer) ? 2 : 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use such id in the selector itself?

```
  $('#supper-offer:not(.slick-initialized)').slick({
      arrows: true,
      slidesToShow: 2
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try using ternary like Dakota Raymond answered.

I'm writing this answer to help you retrieve the id of the element. Try using

```
slidesToShow : $(this).attr('id') == 'supper-offer' ? 2 : 3
```